# ListView duplicates last item upon refresh

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to display a list of last conversations that a user has had from `Firebase Database`. I am using nested `ValueEventListeners` so that I first retrieve the `chatroom IDs` that the current user is involved with, and then upon those IDs, I get the latest activity (from that chatroom) and create an object accordingly that gets added to the ListView.

When the fragment is created, the list of chatRooms is well loaded, as shown [here](https://imgur.com/a/HyE7I). Yet, if another user sends the current user another message, **the last item gets duplicated** (somehow it gets the previous stamp but the same text from the latest message) as shown [here](https://imgur.com/a/OCJAE).

**What is causing this behavior?**

**MyChatsFragment.java**

```
public class MyChatsFragment extends Fragment {

private ListView listView;

public MyChatsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_chats, container, false);

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    final DatabaseReference databaseReference = database.getReference();
    final DatabaseReference ChatMembersReference = databaseReference.child("chat_members");

    final FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (currentUser != null) {
        final String currentUID = currentUser.getUid();

        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.MyChatsList);


        Query filterQuery = ChatMembersReference.orderByChild(currentUID).equalTo(true);
        filterQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                final List<ChatInfo> my_chats = new ArrayList<ChatInfo>();

                for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    final String ChatRoom = child.getKey();
                    // ADD VALUE EVENT LISTENER
                    databaseReference.child("chat_info").child(ChatRoom).child("lastStamp").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            long lastMessageStamp = (long) dataSnapshot.getValue();

                            ChatInfo currentChatInfo = new ChatInfo(ChatRoom, lastMessageStamp);
                            my_chats.add(currentChatInfo);
                            // HERE WE HAVE TO SORT
                            if (my_chats.size() > 1) {
                                Collections.sort(my_chats, new Comparator<ChatInfo>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public int compare(ChatInfo o1, ChatInfo o2) {
                                        if (o1.getLastMessageTimeStamp() < o2.getLastMessageTimeStamp()) {
                                            return -1;
                                        } else if (o1.getLastMessageTimeStamp() > o2.getLastMessageTimeStamp()) {
                                            return 1;
                                        }
                                        return 0;
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            Collections.reverse(my_chats);

                            MyChatsAdapter myChatsAdapter = new MyChatsAdapter(getActivity(), my_chats);
                            listView.setAdapter(myChatsAdapter);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
      }
    return view;
    }


   }
```

**MyChatsAdapter.java**: [check this gist please](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4fb4f0bab87a47ed9c97758ccf585b28)

Comment: It's also duplicated in the database or only when you display it?